# Terminate Workflow from custom code activity

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

Is it possible to terminate a workflow from within a custom code activity?  I'd like to change my code activity to end the workflow if certain conditions are met otherwise carry on.

I've found System.Workflow.ComponentModel.TerminateActivity but i'd like to call it from within my custom code activity.

I've got

```
System.Workflow.ComponentModel.TerminateActivity Terminate = new System.Workflow.ComponentModel.TerminateActivity();
```

but how to i execute the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options that I see:

1. set something (eg a Variable) that can be inspected throughout your Workflow, and use regular conditional branching (eg If activities) to decide the flow.
2. throw an exception from C#/VB, and have it leak out uncaught

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Activities.Statements.TerminateWorkflow terminator =
    new System.Activities.Statements.TerminateWorkflow();
terminator.Reason = "TEST";
```